# Dúvida com ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-repeat

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div id="box-1" class="box">
   <div ng-repeat="task in contato " style="margin-top: 5px">
      <div class="md-card md-card-hover">
          <div class="md-card-content">
              <div style="margin-top:-20px">
                  <span>Cliente: {{ task.razao}}</span><br />
                  <span>valor_negocio: {{ task.valor_negocio}}</span><br />
                  <span>valor_mensalidade: {{ task.valor_mensalidade}}</span><br />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="box-2" class="box">
     <div ng-repeat="task in Andamento" style="margin-top: 5px">
         <div class="md-card md-card-warning md-card-hover">
             <div class="md-card-content">
                 <span>Cliente: {{ task.razao}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_negocio: {{ task.valor_negocio}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_mensalidade: {{ task.valor_mensalidade}}</span><br />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="box-3" class="box">
     <div ng-repeat="task in fechado" style="margin-top: 5px">
         <div class="md-card md-card-success md-card-hover">
             <div class="md-card-content">
                 <span>Cliente: {{ task.razao}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_negocio: {{ task.valor_negocio}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_mensalidade: {{ task.valor_mensalidade}}</span><br />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="box-4" class="box">
     <div ng-repeat="task in perdido" style="margin-top: 5px">
         <div class="md-card md-card-danger md-card-hover">
             <div class="md-card-content">
                 <span>Cliente: {{ task.razao}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_negocio: {{ task.valor_negocio}}</span><br />
                 <span>valor_mensalidade: {{ task.valor_mensalidade}}</span><br />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

E no meu controller tenhos os array de json:

```
 $scope.contato = [
   { "id": "1", "razao": "ADEMIR DA", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
   { "id": "2", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
   { "id": "3", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
   { "id": "4", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" }
];

$scope.Andamento = [
    { "id": "1", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
    { "id": "2", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" }
];

$scope.fechado = [
    { "id": "1", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
    { "id": "2", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
    { "id": "3", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" }
];

$scope.perdido = [
   { "id": "1", "razao": "ADEMIA", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
    { "id": "2", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" },
    { "id": "3", "razao": "ADEMIR", "titulo": "dfgdfg", "descricao": "GDFGDFG", "valor_negocio": " 5345.00 ", "valor_mensalidade": "5.00" }
];
```

este é o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso fazer para que os espaços vazios (quando um array tem mais itens que os outros), fiquem na parte inferior?

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    border-color: blue;
    text-align: left;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: 200px;
    /*margin: 5px 5px;*/
}

.cabecalho {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: 20px;
    /*margin: 5px 5px;*/
}

#box-1 {
    background-color: white;
}

#box-2 {
    background-color: white;
}

#box-3 {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: você usa qual framework CSS?

Comment: uso esse template http://preview.themeforest.net/item/altair-admin-material-design-uikit-template/full_screen_preview/12190654

Comment: pra reproduzir o seu exemplo precisa definir esse layout, o framework CSS, o problema apresentando nada mais é do que alguma configuração CSS

Comment: como ficaria um css que forçaria os itens irem para o topo?

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta todos arquivos css, porque o normal.seria já no topo.então tem que alterar o que esta no site ...

Comment: o template tem trocentos mil css, vou ter q dar um jeito de forçar isso via JS

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse `class="box"` no css ta assim `.box { // code` passa esse código! acho que é ele!

Comment: Editei e colei o Css, de uma olhada ai

Comment: precisaria montar um template para te ajudar melhor, mas o flexbox do css3 vai te ajuda você fazer isso... de uma nesse link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Não vejo o CSS como a forma de ordenar por dados completos ou faltantes, acredito que tratar os dados seria a forma mais robusta dessa solução. No exemplo mostrado, porém, daria pra utilizar flex-box com flex-direction=row-reverse e ele inverteria a ordem, mas só funciona no exemplo mostrado pois os elementos com dados faltantes estão no início da lista, logo não é uma solução para outros casos.

Answer (score -2):

utilize `vertical-align: top;` em `.box`

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. Crie um exemplo ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score -3):

O exemplo é uma adaptação menor da sua pergunta, digamos que seu HTML seja:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="box__wrapper">
      <div class="card">
         <h1>Card 1</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, eum!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
         <h1>Card 2</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, eum!</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Você pode usar flexbox para alinhar os itens ao fundo da div:

```
.box{
   display: flex;
   width: 24%;
   height: 600px;
   background: red;
   padding: 20px;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box__wrapper{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   gap: 8px;
   width: 100%;
}

.card{
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px black solid;
   padding: 1rem;
   width: 100%;
}
```